# Django update() is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I have a function that changes the details of my models when triggered. I cannot get it to do the work I intend to have it do.
I can't tell why this is so.
Any help will greately be appreciated.

The error code:

```
    @login_required(login_url='/login/')
    def move_students(request):
        try:
            Klass.objects.filter(school=request.user.school,name=1).update(name=2)
        except Exception as e:
            messages.info(request,f'erroerd at {e}')
        return redirect('/')
```

Model:

```
    class Klass(models.Model):
        name = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5),], help_text='E.g 1,2,3, 4')
        school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Classes'
            unique_together = ("school", "name")
```

Stacktrace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Python\Django\Completed Projects\lib_system\Library-System\libman\views.py", line 29, in move_students
        Klass.objects.filter(school=request.user.school,name=1).update(name=2)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 784, in update
        rows = query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1522, in execute_sql
        cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: libman_klass.school_id, libman_klass.name
    [09/Jun/2021 11:14:57] "GET /library/move/students HTTP/1.1" 500 125470
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: libman_klass.school_id, libman_klass.name`. This means that the `unique_together`  on your models is throwing an error as you are trying to save a `school` and `name` which already exists in the database.

For example the code below, a `Klass` with the `school=request.user.school` and `name=2` already exists but you have a unique together constraint to prevent this.

```
Klass.objects.filter(school=request.user.school,name=1).update(name=2)
```

If you don't want this, remove the `unique_together` constraint and run migrations again (`./manage.py makemigrations` `./manage.py migrate`) or except an `IntegrityError`:

```
try:
    Klass.objects.filter(
        school=request.user.school,
        name=1
    ).update(name=2)
except IntegrityError as e:
    # do something 
    messages.info(request,f'erroerd at {e}')
return redirect('/')
```

Comment: You need to remove the `unique_together` inside your model and run migrations again. Or you can except an `IntegrityError` and handle it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the `IntegrityError` handling.